# Bibtex issues with subfile

Tags: bibtex, subfiles

Good day
I am attempting to cite in a subfile using a global BibTeX file but I keep getting the following error

> You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

My code is as follows. For my `main.tex` I have

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{note_fontcolor}{rgb}{0.800781, 0.800781, 0.800781}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{subfiles} 

\doublespacing

\makeatletter
% curse you, \@onlypreamble\@ifclassloaded
\newcommand*{\subfilesbibliography}[1]{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@subfiles.cls\endcsname\relax
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \else
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {\bibliography{#1}}
  {}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
%% The greyedout annotation environment
\newenvironment{lyxgreyedout}
{\textcolor{note_fontcolor}\bgroup\ignorespaces}
{\ignorespacesafterend\egroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\ifx\proof\undefined
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\protect\proofname]{\par
    \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \itemindent\parindent
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape #1]\ignorespaces
}{%
    \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\providecommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,natbib,amssymb,wrapfig,threeparttable,rotating}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

    \subfile{Sections/Introduction}
    

\newpage

\bibliography{My_lib}
\end{document}
```

`Introduction.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
Cluster analysis \cite{hoff_subset_2005} is a popular...

\subfilesbibliography{My_lib}
\end{document}
```

The My_lib.bib file was exported from Zotero as a Bibtex file and this is its entry

```
@article{hoff_subset_2005,
    title = {Subset {Clustering} of {Binary} {Sequences}, with an {Application} to {Genomic} {Abnormality} {Data}},
    volume = {61},
    issn = {1541-0420},
    url = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2005.00381.x},
    doi = {10.1111/j.1541-0420.2005.00381.x},
    abstract = {This article develops a model-based approach to clustering multivariate binary data, in which the attributes that distinguish a cluster from the rest of the population may depend on the cluster being considered. The clustering approach is based on a multivariate Dirichlet process mixture model, which allows for the estimation of the number of clusters, the cluster memberships, and the cluster-specific parameters in a unified way. Such a clustering approach has applications in the analysis of genomic abnormality data, in which the development of different types of tumors may depend on the presence of certain abnormalities at subsets of locations along the genome. Additionally, such a mixture model provides a nonparametric estimation scheme for dependent sequences of binary data.},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2021-09-28},
    journal = {Biometrics},
    author = {Hoff, Peter D.},
    year = {2005},
    note = {\_eprint: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2005.00381.x},
    keywords = {Genetic pathway, Multivariate binary data, Nonparametric Bayes, Unsupervised learning},
    pages = {1027--1036},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\Pottie\\Zotero\\storage\\9JT58QWX\\j.1541-0420.2005.00381.html:text/html;Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\Pottie\\Zotero\\storage\\NM6C2AGC\\Hoff - 2005 - Subset Clustering of Binary Sequences, with an App.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

The key that I am using is exactly the same as in the My_lib.bib file so I do not understand when my citations aren't working.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In `Introduction.tex`, replace

```
\subfilesbibliography{My_lib}
```

by

```
\subfilesbibliography{../My_lib}
```

The general philosophy is that filenames in a subfile are relative to the subfile.

With recent versions of the `subfiles` package, you don't have to define `\subfilesbibliography` but can replace the above line by

```
\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{\bibliography{../My_lib}}{}% \ifSubfilesClassLoaded{then branch}{else branch}
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{\bibliography{../My_Lib}}{}` ->     `BibTeX: I couldn't open database file ../My_Lib.bib : \bibdata{../My_Lib : }`

Comment: Actually, I see now that I get that error for both the proposed solution. Could there be something else that I am missing?

Comment: @Susan-l3p Please edit your original posting and make sure that the code given there is exactly the code you use, including filenames and directory structure. E.g., the colon in `\bibdata{../My_Lib :  }` in your comment looks strange. Moreover, make sure that you use a recent version of `subfiles` (2020/11/14 v2.2). If you are bound to use another version, add the version number.